# Can normal distribution be used to model the percentage of occurances?

Tags: normal-distribution

The title doesn't explain my question very well, so I will use an example to explain this further.

Say, I record the percentage of people exiting a supermarket from $1-2\text{pm}$ who use their own bag instead of a plastic bag for $100$ days. Say, that the data I obtain is approximately normal. Can a normal distribution be used to model this despite the fact that $x$ terminates at $0\text{% and } 100\text%$ because it's a percentage?

Comment: You might be interested in another approach, "logistic regression": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution extends to infinity in both directions, but it is very small a few standard deviations from the mean.  You can create a new distribution by truncating the normal distribution at some limits.  You should rescale the distribution to keep the area $1$, but if you only cut off the tails that is a small effect.